# Storage access framework - show specific file in ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT file picker

Tags: android

I am using the Storage Access Framework to delete a specific file.  I already know which specific file the user would like to delete.  Is there a way to just show the user this specific file in the file picker? Currently, it always opens from the root directory and then the user has to navigate to the file.  This is a usability issue.

Or, is there a way to just request the desired permission?

Comment: You want to directly open the directory, in which the file you want to delete, in file browser?

Comment: Yes, if that's possible.  Or, even better, it would just pop up directly to the file already selected.

Comment: Do you need a File Picker itself or a File Dialog is ok with you?

Comment: A file dialog is fine if that is possible.  I am trying to delete the file on the sdcard for platforms KitKat+ which I believe has to use the Storage Access Framework.  I am not sure if that has a file dialog.

Comment: See the answer below. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
package com.test.filedialog.file;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import com.test.filedialog.file.ListenerList.FireHandler;

public class FileDialog {
    private static final String PARENT_DIR = "..";
    private final String TAG = getClass().getName();
    private String[] fileList;
    private File currentPath;

    public interface FileSelectedListener {
        void fileSelected(File file);
    }

    public interface DirectorySelectedListener {
        void directorySelected(File directory);
    }

    private ListenerList<FileSelectedListener> fileListenerList = new ListenerList<FileSelectedListener>();
    private ListenerList<DirectorySelectedListener> dirListenerList = new ListenerList<DirectorySelectedListener>();
    private final Activity activity;
    private boolean selectDirectoryOption;
    private String fileEndsWith;
    private String[] fileEndsWiths;   

    /**
     * @param activity 
     * @param initialPath - HERE IS WHERE YOU SHOULD GIVE THE DIRECTORY YOU WANT
     */
    public FileDialog(Activity activity, File initialPath) {
        this.activity = activity;
        if (!path.exists()) path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        loadFileList(path);
    }

    /**
     * @return file dialog
     */
    public Dialog createFileDialog() {
        Dialog dialog = null;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

        builder.setTitle(currentPath.getPath());
        if (selectDirectoryOption) {
            builder.setPositiveButton("Select directory", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.d(TAG, currentPath.getPath());
                    fireDirectorySelectedEvent(currentPath);
                }
            });
        }

        builder.setItems(fileList, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String fileChosen = fileList[which];
                File chosenFile = getChosenFile(fileChosen);
                if (chosenFile.isDirectory()) {
                    loadFileList(chosenFile);
                    dialog.cancel();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    showDialog();
                } else fireFileSelectedEvent(chosenFile);
            }
        });

        dialog = builder.show();
        return dialog;
    }    

    public void addFileListener(FileSelectedListener listener) {
        fileListenerList.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeFileListener(FileSelectedListener listener) {
        fileListenerList.remove(listener);
    }

    public void setSelectDirectoryOption(boolean selectDirectoryOption) {
        this.selectDirectoryOption = selectDirectoryOption;
    }

    public void addDirectoryListener(DirectorySelectedListener listener) {
        dirListenerList.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeDirectoryListener(DirectorySelectedListener listener) {
        dirListenerList.remove(listener);
    }

    /**
     * Show file dialog
     */
    public void showDialog() {
        createFileDialog().show();
    }

    private void fireFileSelectedEvent(final File file) {
        fileListenerList.fireEvent(new FireHandler<FileSelectedListener>() {
            public void fireEvent(FileSelectedListener listener) {
                listener.fileSelected(file);
            }
        });
    }

    private void fireDirectorySelectedEvent(final File directory) {
        dirListenerList.fireEvent(new FireHandler<DirectorySelectedListener>() {
            public void fireEvent(DirectorySelectedListener listener) {
                listener.directorySelected(directory);
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadFileList(File path) {
        this.currentPath = path;
        List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (path.exists()) {
            if (path.getParentFile() != null) r.add(PARENT_DIR);
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                    File sel = new File(dir, filename);

                    if (!sel.canRead()) return false;
                    if (selectDirectoryOption) return sel.isDirectory();
                    else {
                        boolean endsWith = false;
                        if(fileEndsWiths != null){
                            System.out.println("File Input Lengths : " + fileEndsWiths.length);
                            for(int i = 0; i < fileEndsWiths.length; i++){
                                endsWith = fileEndsWiths[i] != null ? filename.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).endsWith(fileEndsWiths[i]) : true;
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            endsWith = fileEndsWith != null ? filename.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).endsWith(fileEndsWith) : true;
                            System.out.println("No Files");
                        }                       

                        return endsWith || sel.isDirectory();
                    }
                }
            };
//            String[] fileList1 = path.list(filter);
            File[] fileList1 = path.listFiles();
            for (File file : fileList1) {
                r.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
        fileList = (String[]) r.toArray(new String[]{});
    }

    private File getChosenFile(String fileChosen) {
        if (fileChosen.equals(PARENT_DIR)) return currentPath.getParentFile();
        else return new File(currentPath, fileChosen);
    }

    public void setFileEndsWith(String[] fileEndsWith) {
        this.fileEndsWiths = fileEndsWith;
    }

    public void setFileEndsWith(String fileEndsWith) {
        this.fileEndsWith = fileEndsWith != null ? fileEndsWith.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()) : fileEndsWith;
    }
 }

class ListenerList<L> {
    private List<L> listenerList = new ArrayList<L>();

    public interface FireHandler<L> {
        void fireEvent(L listener);
    }

    public void add(L listener) {
        listenerList.add(listener);
    }

    public void fireEvent(FireHandler<L> fireHandler) {
        List<L> copy = new ArrayList<L>(listenerList);
        for (L l : copy) {
            fireHandler.fireEvent(l);
        }
    }

    public void remove(L listener) {
        listenerList.remove(listener);
    }

    public List<L> getListenerList() {
        return listenerList;
    }
}
```

In order to browse and receive the selected file, use the following.

```
private void browseFiles(){
    File mPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "//DIR//");
    FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(getActivity(), mPath);
    /**
     * Specify the file type here
     * **/
    String[] fileTypes = new String[] { ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".PNG", ".JPG", ".JPEG", ".gif", ".GIF", ".tif", ".TIF"};
    //This fileTypes Array is optional
    fileDialog.setFileEndsWith(fileTypes);
    fileDialog.setFileEndsWith(".png");

    fileDialog.addFileListener(new FileDialog.FileSelectedListener() {
        public void fileSelected(File file) {
            //file is the selected File
        }
    });

    fileDialog.showDialog();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Actually, if I use the file dialog on kitkat or higher and try to use it to delete a file, I still get the permission error.  I guess I need to use the Storage Access Framework.  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

Comment: You can still incorporate Permission model with this solution actually. I have integrated this with Permission model successfully in couple of apps.